# An inequality involving states and positive linear functional on a $C^*$-algebra

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be a unital $C^*$-algebra. Let $\varphi$ be a state on $\mathcal{A}$. Let $\psi$ be a positive linear functional on $\mathcal{A}$ such that $\psi\le \phi$.
Let $0\le a \le 1$ be an element in $\mathcal{A}$.
Is it true that $\psi(a)\le\varphi(a)\psi\left(1_{\mathcal{A}}\right)$?

My attempt: Since $a$ is non-negative, I can write $$\varphi(a)\psi\left(1_\mathcal{A}\right)-\psi(a)=\left(\varphi(a)^{\frac{1}{2}}\psi\left(1_\mathcal{A}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}-\psi(a)^{\frac{1}{2}}\right)\left(\varphi(a)^{\frac{1}{2}}\psi\left(1_\mathcal{A}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}+\psi(a)^{\frac{1}{2}}\right)$$

Clearly, $\left(\varphi(a)^{\frac{1}{2}}\psi\left(1_\mathcal{A}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}+\psi(a)^{\frac{1}{2}}\right)\ge 0$. All I need to show is that $\left(\varphi(a)^{\frac{1}{2}}\psi\left(1_\mathcal{A}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}-\psi(a)^{\frac{1}{2}}\right)\ge0$ in order to prove the claim.

The only thing which I know is the Cauchy-Schwartz inequality. So, I resorted to using it. Using it,
$$\psi(a)\le \psi(a^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}\psi(1_{\mathcal{A}})^{\frac{1}{2}}\le \varphi(a^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}\psi(1_{\mathcal{A}})^{\frac{1}{2}}$$
Since $0\le a \le 1$, we see that $a^2=a^{\frac{1}{2}}aa^{\frac{1}{2}}\le a^{\frac{1}{2}}1_{\mathcal{A}}a^{\frac{1}{2}}=a$. Using that $\varphi$ is a state, we obtain that
$$\psi(a)\le \varphi(a)^{\frac{1}{2}}\psi(1_{\mathcal{A}})^{\frac{1}{2}}.$$

All I am missing is a square root on the left hand side. Is there a way to fix it? Is the inequality even true?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: This cannot hold in broad generality (when $\psi(1)<1$) because of very elementary reasoning: it's like asking if we know that $a\le b$ for some numbers, then can we conclude that $a\le (1-\epsilon)b$, which, will be impossible, since we are not excluding the case $a=b$. Similar to this, it can happen that $\psi,\phi$ assign the same values to elements, hence it would be impossible to dominate $\psi$ uniformly by something of the form $(1-\epsilon)\phi$

Answer (score 2):

The inequality does not hold. Consider the two dimensional $C^*$-algebra of functions defined on $\{0,1\}.$ Let $\varphi(f)={1\over 2}[f(0)+f(1)]$ and
$\psi(f)={1\over 6}f(0)+{1\over 2}f(1).$ Then $\psi\le \varphi$ and $\psi(1)={2\over 3}.$ However
${2\over 3}\varphi(f)={1\over 3}f(0)+{1\over 3}f(1).$ Hence the required inequality does not hold.

In general if $\psi (1)\neq 0$ then $\tilde{\psi}=\psi(1)^{-1}\psi$ is a state. The inequality $\tilde{\psi}\le \varphi$ implies $\tilde{\psi}=\varphi,$ i.e. $\psi $ is a multiple of $\varphi.$